# How can I programmatically change an RFC3339 timezone offset in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone-offset

I'm wondering how I can programmatically change an RFC3339 DateTime's timezone offset in Ruby 2.3 (ActiveSupport is available, if that'd help).

I'd like to convert: `2016-06-22T00:00:00+00:00` into `2016-06-22T00:00:00-04:00` without resorting to string substitution.

EDIT: Per the Tin Man's request, I'll elaborate on what I've tried. As alluded to above, I tried using `String#sub` to find-and-replace the offending section of the original string. That worked, but I considered it to be a kludge and wanted to find a solution that made use of the Time/Date API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see what you've tried. As is it looks like you're asking us to do the research and/or write a tutorial, but that's not what SO is for. What code have you written to solve this? Please read "[ask]", including the linked pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`DateTime#change`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/change), you can pass in an offset.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date_time'

DateTime.now.change(offset: '-0400')
#=> Wed, 22 Jun 2016 23:47:34 -0400
```